# Manipulate session data after Azure AD authentication ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core application where users need to log in using Azure AD. I have implemented this as described in the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp-calls-graph

There's a database attached to the application, in which I have described user roles, and based on those roles I want to fill in what is visible, what the user can do, etc.

How can I add the data from the database to the session after logon, so I have access to that data on every page?